# Typescript capture type at key in array as in object-like structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let say i have a structure like this:

```
type Dict<T = any> = {[key: string]: T}

type AsObject<T extends Dict> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (x: any) => T[K]
}
```

What i do need is the same structure as an array, but how to capture the type for that specific key in the function?

```
type AsArray<T extends Dict> = {
  key: keyof T
  fn: (x: any) => T[??] // how to get typeof key from here ?
}[]
```

Comment: `Record<T>` is an existing type that covers what your Dict type does

Comment: Could you explain better what do you mean by key in function? As a in a key in the object return of that function? as functions unlike objects do not have keys

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh i ment by key the specific key in the object holding a function (in AsObject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure the array items have the corect combination of `type` and `fn`, you can, using a mapped type, create a union of al valid possibilities for the array item and then use this to define the array:

```
type Dict<T = any> = Record<string, T>

type AllPosibilities<T extends Dict> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        type: K,
        fn: (x: any) => T[K]
    }
}[keyof T]

type AsArray<T extends Dict> = AllPosibilities<T>[]

let arr : AsArray <{
    "a": string,
    "b": number
}> = [
    { type: "a", fn: (x) => "" }, //ok
    { type: "b", fn: (x) => "" },// err
    { type: "b", fn: (x) => 1 }  //ok
]
```